# is it possible to trigger Jenkins/TeamCity from SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, teamcity, sonarqube-scan

what I want to do is, trigger build from SonarQube.

When new PR created at GitHub, GitHub sends a payload to the SonarQube server. From there I want to trigger a build in Jenkins/TeamCity by using that pull request information come. The SonarQube server is accessible from GitHub, but not Jenkins/TeamCity server.  I found a plugin to trigger build in Jenkins but I want to trigger build from SonarQube.

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know it is working only in this way:

GitLab -> Jenkins -> SonarQube

something triggers jenknis build, jenkins triggers sonarqube.